# What to do with changes after git rebase?

Tags: git, workflow, rebase

I am rebasing one branch `feature` on another branch `master`. During the rebase some files are auto-merged in a way that causes compilation errors when the rebase is complete. I fix these errors on the now-rebased `feature` branch and thus have a set if changed files.

Ideally I would like the commit log to *only* hold commits from `master`, then commits from `feature` (and no other commits), but the changes have to go somewhere.

What is your "best practice" of handling such changes resulting from rebasing? Do you put them in a separate commit on `feature`? Squash them into an existing commit on `feature` (I'm going to force push anyway)?

Or is there a way to avoid this problem altogether? E.g., is there a way that I can stop the rebasing *after* the last commit from `feature` is applied, but *before*  git registers the rebasing as completed? If there is I could build and fix at this time and then do a final `git rebase --continue`

Comment: If you don't want any commits from the `feature` branch, but only the latest base coming from `master`, then why are you rebasing here in the first place?

Comment: I want all commits from `master` _and_  commits from `feature`. What I'd like to avoid is any extra commits like "Changes required after rebasing on master"

Comment: If you have conflicts or other similar issues, then manual remediation might always be necessary.  But still, this doesn't create new commits.  A normal rebase already meets the requirements of your comment just above this.  There are no "extra" commits here.

Comment: As I stated, the problems arise in *auto-merged* files, the ones that I do not manually resolve conflicts in. The auto-merged changes result in build errors when the rebasing is complete. I then have to make changes in these files to fix the errors, which results in a set of changed files.

Comment: You don't need to stop rebasing at the last commit to make changes. Just complete the rebase and then run your tests. If changes are required (for whatever reason), fix them and amend the last commit.

Comment: @matt, yes, that is what I considered first. Being a purist, however, I would ideally like to not have the changes "pollute" the latest, probably unrelated, commit on the feature branch. But then again, the changes have to go somewhere I guess.

Comment: @CorpusGigantus To solve it properly (ultra-puristic?), you would need to make/amend the changes in the commit where they actually would be required. Just doing them in the last (possibly unrelated) commit might totally change its intent. Let's say the last commit changes the readme and has a message describing this. Amending some additional fixes would basically require changing the commit message. Now, the question is if the fixes should really go into the same commit or not...

Comment: ... frame-challenge for a situation before rebasing: When your branch does not compile anymore because of a change 2-3 commits ago and only realise it now. How would you commit it? Rewinding history and doing it where the problematic code got introduced? In an independent commit? Together with the next commit with a message "added x and fixed y"? Or just with the message "added x" and fixing it silently? These were purely rhetorical questions with totally opinionated answers. It might help to find your personal choice what to do after a rebase as the situation is more or less the same.

Comment: @Matt. Thanks for your comment. I like this approach to thinking about it. Amending a previous commit or adding a new one will be my general solutions, which one will be dictated by individual scenarios. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that rebase works by *copying* commits.  The original commits remain unchanged.  For instance, suppose you have the following series of commits:

```
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Here, Alice made commits `I` and `J` one after the other atop commit `H` (each of these letters stands in for some big ugly Git hash ID).  Around the same time (shortly before and/or afterward), Bob made commits `K` and `L` atop master.

Someone—the best case is usually that this "someone" is Alice herself—is now given the job of coming up with some *new and improved* commits, which we will call `I'` and `J'`, that are a great deal *like* commits `I` and `J` but which:

- come after `K`-and-`L`;
- have different *snapshots* because they are *based on* `K` and `L`; and
- have any other changes needed to make them work.

Alice can run:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

and Git will do its best to make new commits `I'` and `J'` on its own:

```
                I'-J'  <-- feature
               /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

If *Git* thinks it's going badly, *Git* will stop and demand that Alice fix any *merge conflicts* that Git has detected *during this copying process*, before Git moves the branch name `feature` to locate commit `J'`.  But Git is not very smart, and if Git thinks everything is going smoothly, Git will just run right on ahead and finish the rebase, producing these copies that don't actually *work*.

If that's the case, it's *Alice's job* (or whoever is doing the rebase) to *control Git*.  She can use `git rebase -i` and replace one or all `pick` commands with `edit` commands instead, for instance.  Git will then stop after each cherry-pick—remember that rebase's commit copying is a series of `git cherry-pick` operations—and allow Alice to *fix up the commit*.  She can build and test the system, locate any bugs, make some edits, and run `git add` and `git commit --amend` as necessary to repair them, replacing, e.g.:

```
                I'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

with:

```
                I'  [abandoned]
               /
              | I"  <-- HEAD
              |/
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

and then run `git rebase --continue` to have Git go on to cherry-pick `J` to make `J'` and then stop again due to another `edit`:

```
                I'  [abandoned]
               /
              | I"-J'  <-- HEAD
              |/
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Should it be necessary, Alice can now use `git commit --amend` as before (along with the pre-commit steps) to replace `J'` with `J"`.

The final result is, presumably a working series of replacement commits.  When the rebase is complete, Git moves the name `feature` to point to the last of the copied commits:

```
                I'  [abandoned]
               /
              | I"-J'  <-- feature
              |/
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

Removing the abandoned (and invisible) commits from this picture, we now have a completely working updated `feature`.  The fact that the hash IDs of new copies `I"` (modified from `I'` to make it work) and `J'` (which worked right off the bat after all) differ from those of the original `I` and `J` is equally invisible since no *human* ever notices these hash IDs.

(Note, however, that *Git* notices the hash IDs—in fact, those are what Git *really* cares about—so it's important that Alice **and everyone else** be careful not to reintroduce the original `I` and `J` commits.  Only Alice has any temporary commits made during the rebase-and-edit procedure, so only Alice has to be careful not to reintroduce those, and it's unlikely that Alice will do so accidentally.  But if commits `I` and `J` were given out to other Git users, and those other Git users have them now, those other Git users could easily reintroduce `I` and `J` accidentally.)

#### This is not your only option

If you're Alice, you can:

- do the entire rebase all at once;
- check for errors only once, at the end;
- localize those errors; and
- use `git rebase -i` to pick specific commits to modify.

You can also make "fixup" commits with `git commit --fixup`, then use `git rebase -i --autosquash` to have Git helpfully update the interactive rebase command sheet.  This is a more advanced way to achieve the same result as above.

(Note that it's easy to miss a bad *intermediate* commit this way, if the final commit somehow fixes it up.)

#### Additional rebase tricks

If you have automated tests that will find these problems—this can be as simple as a failed compilation, perhaps—consider adding `-x command` to a rebase.  This uses the interactive machinery—you can use `git rebase -i` here, in other words—to run a command after each `pick` (or pick-and-fixup etc; see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for details).  If the supplied command fails, the rebase will stop automatically.  If not, it will go on to the next `pick`.

Having good automated tests is extremely helpful here.

If the tests are very slow, consider doing the full rebase followed by a single test, and if that fails, using `git bisect` to find the failure point.